# SQL Always Encrypted vs SQL Dynamic Data Masking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am undecided on two methods to hide data in a single column in SQL Server DB.

`1. SQL Always Encrypted`

`2. SQL Dynamic Data Masking`

After reading articles for both, my understanding is that `Always Encrypted` may be more secure than `Dynamic Data Masking` as the data stored is encrypted instead of the putting a mask on top of the password.

However, what are the impacts when it comes to daily usage in this scenario if the user simply wants to hide the password field from database administrators?

> Data to be hidden: Password
>
> Functions using Password column: Reset password, change password, insert new password row when creating new user

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

*P.S. My initial plan was to use SHA1+Salt hashing to password fields and storing hash values instead of password. However, if the requirements are simply to hide the field in DB, I find that the other 2 methods above may be sufficient.*

Comment: don't use SHA1. Best practice is to store a Salted then Hashed password (use a stronger hash than SHA1: use SHA2_256 or SHA2_512 ) With a separate (stored) salt for each hashed password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under no circumstances should the password ever be stored on a database table, or anywhere for that matter, period.

You should hash the password and store the hashed value. Consider using SHA 2, or higher, with salting.

See NIST for more details: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Hash-Functions

SQL Server 2008+ supports up to SHA2-512:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
DECLARE @HashThis NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @HashThis);
```

To see how the password can be salted, see the article below. It is worth pointing out that hashing and salting should be handled at the application layer because the DBA can see the password that is being salted in SQL Profiler. Be very careful.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3293/add-a-salt-with-the-sql-server-hashbytes-function/

Additional Info:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/

Final point: If, by any chance, you are performing this exercise as a means to authenticate users in a web application, then you should look for authentication modules for the specified application framework. For example, ASP.NET comes with Microsoft's Identity 2.0 system, which handles the authentication process end-to-end.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: May I know for HashBytes, the value of `dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf`, is the value hard coded in the backend code?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the PW from the DB administrator, then dynamic data masking is off the table. This simply masks it at the presentation layer.

AlwaysEncrypted moves the responsibility of encryption to the client application, meaning the encryption and decryption is handled outside of the application, leaving the data unreadable to the database administrator generally speaking.

So, it depends on your definition of *hiding*. If you want it hidden from administrators... Always Encrypted is where you need to focus.

**EDIT**

Always Encrypted is only available in 2016 for starters, but column level encryption has been available since 2005. But to answer your question, no, the DBA doesn't have to have the keys to the kingdom. AE was designed to handle the encryption and decryption at the driver level. The information below is from the [official 70-764 exam reference by Victor Isakov](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/exam-ref-70-764-administering-a-sql-database-infrastructure/fgqpf3gzmxqc?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab):

At a high level the AE architecture works as shown in Figure 1-5:

1. The client application issues a parameterized query. It uses the new Column Encryption Setting=Enabled; option in the connection string
2. The enhanced ADO.NET driver interrogates the database engine using the [sp_describe_parameter_encryption] system stored procedure to determine which parameters target encrypted columns. For each parameter that will require encrypting the driver retrieves the encryption algorithm and other information that will be used during the encryption phase
3. The driver uses the Column Master Key (CMK) to encrypt the parameter values before sending the ciphertext to the database engine.
4. The database engine retrieves the result set, attaching the appropriate encryption metadata to any encrypted columns, and sends it back to the client application. The data is encrypted both at rest within the database and in flight from the database engine to the client application.
5. The client application’s driver decrypts any encrypted

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. May I verify, AlwaysEncrypted, the Administrator would hold the Master key. Wouldn't it result in that specific user account having access to the data too?

Comment: @gymcode i added an edit to the answer, but the short answer to your question is no.